# Validate JWT using swagger .net core 6 API

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, swagger

I am trying to authorize a token using swagger. See the image below. My issue is when I type in an invalid token, I don't get any errors or anything.
[image]

Below is the API

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("GetUsers")]
public IEnumerable<CountryOutputDto> GetCountriesList()
{
    return _countryAppService.GetCountries();
}
```

Below is are my settings

// Add Authencation

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JWTToken_Auth_API", Version = "v1" });

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 1safsfsdfdfd\"",
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
      {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
        Reference = new OpenApiReference
        {
        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
        Id = "Bearer"
        }
        },
        new string[] {}
      }
    });

});


     "JsonWebTokenKeys": {
    "ValidateIssuerSigningKey": true,
    "IssuerSigningKey": "64A63153-11C1-4919-9133-EFAF99A9B456",
    "ValidateIssuer": false,
    "ValidIssuer": "https://localhost:8100",
    "ValidateAudience": false,
    "ValidAudience": "https://localhost:8100",
    "RequireExpirationTime": true,
    "ValidateLifetime": true
  }
```

Comment: swagger not going to validate any tokens. main purpose of Swagger is documentation. after request sent your service is going to validate is that token is valid or not

Comment: Have you implement JWT by registering AddAuthentication() , AddJwtBearer() . I suggest you to refer https://codepedia.info/jwt-authentication-in-aspnet-core-web-api-token and get basic understanding on JWT implementation in asp.net core

Comment: @Satindersingh my  issue was I thought you can use the key that you set from the appsettings.json file. But the token has to be generated using new JwtSecurityTokenHandler(). Any how I managed to figure it out, its working now.

Comment: swagger is just a tool, If you wanna show some error message, You need to configure it in your service